# Flatten works differently when directly called and when called in a method

Tags: arrays, ruby, flatten

I'm trying to write a method that will take a string consisting of characters `0`, `1`, and `?`, and return the set of strings represented by the original string, taking `?` as a wildcard that can be either a `0` or `1`. For example, if the input is `"011?0"`, then the output should be `["01100", "01110"]`.

I've written the following code:

```
def zerone str, arr
  qs = str.count("?") - 1
  i = 0
  while i < str.length
    if str[i] != "?"
      arr << str[i]
      i += 1
    else
      arr1 = Array.new(arr)
      arr2 = Array.new(arr)
      arr1 << "1"
      arr2 << "0"
      arr = [arr1, arr2]
      arr.map! {|x| zerone(str[i+1..-1], x)}
      break
    end
  end
 arr.flatten(qs)
end
```

When I call `zerone`, I get a flat array:

```
b = zerone("10???", [])
# => ["1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", ...]
```

If I change the last line so the method returns `arr` without calling `flatten`, then I get this:

```
b = zerone("10????", [])
# => [
  [
    [
      [["1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1"], ["1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0"]],
      [["1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1"], ["1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0"]]
    ],
    [
      [["1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1"], ["1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0"]],
      [["1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1"], ["1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0"]]
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      [["1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1"], ["1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0"]],
      [["1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1"], ["1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0"]]
    ],
    [
      [["1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1"], ["1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0"]],
      [["1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1"], ["1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]]
    ]
  ]
]
b.flatten(3)
# => [
  ["1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1"],
  ["1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0"],
  ["1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1"],
  ["1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0"],
  ["1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1"],
  ["1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0"],
  ["1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1"],
  ["1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0"],
  ["1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1"],
  ["1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0"],
  ["1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1"],
  ["1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0"],
  ["1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1"],
  ["1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0"],
  ["1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1"],
  ["1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
]
```

This is what I wanted. Can anyone tell what's going on?

Comment: What do you mean "**your** program should ..."?

Comment: I copied and pasted the description of the problem and apparently failed to change some of the 2nd person pronouns to first person pronouns

Comment: It is not clear what you feel weird.

Comment: Ok I've edited to show more clearly what I don't get about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `zerone` recursively and `qs` is updated and different each time. You are not comparing apples to apples with what the method is doing and what you're manually doing in pry (when removing the flatten).